# Microsoft Access Distinct Not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got the below code, however once run it still shows duplicate Team names. Even within the settings of the query changing 'Unique Values' to yes, I still have the problem.

[image]

Comment: If ID differs the row is not considered unique and will be shown.  If there are multiple IDs for the same name, which one do you want to show?  Based on what logic?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove ID from selected columns, otherwise every record returned by your query will be different.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a range variable then the table's name `Current_Headcount` will be used. However, your query lack any complexity and a range variable is not needed; removing it makes your query slightly easier to read. As others have suggested, you probably want to omit the `ID` column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Team Name]
  FROM Current_Headcount
 ORDER
    BY [Team Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` applies to ALL the fields in the output.